# Laravel 5 - MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

Come across this a few times before when I have been using the wrong option for post / get etc but just jumped back on this project and drawn a blank.

Using angular for the post:

```
$scope.likeUpdate = function(update_id) {
    console.log("clicked");
    $http.post( $rootScope.apiURL + 'updates/likeupdate', {
        update_id : update_id,
        user_id : $rootScope.currentUser.id
    }).success(function(update, response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

And I have a route set up before my resource route:

```
Route::post('updates/likeupdate', 'UpdateController@likeUpdate');
Route::resource('updates', 'UpdateController');
```

But I get the method not allowed error... any ideas on this one?

Comment: Can you please update the question with what the actual request and response looks like from the network tab in firefox/chrome?  It might not be a request to the URL you are expecting.

Comment: @Du3 Not actually working with postman either by requesting the correct URL

Comment: The actual network request will answer a lot of the back and forth.  For instance, if there is a login that needs a web token to be passed in, or a CSRF token authentication going on that angular needs to send. All of this is important to be able to answer the question. If this POST requires a user to be authenticated, that vehicle for authentication might be looking for some data.  Method not allowed sounds like you just are sending the request to a URL that actually doesn't exist, so posting the network request would invalidate that pretty quick. Can you please update with network request?